# question about PackageMaker and scripting

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I am using PackageMaker to create our installer. I want the installer to execute a script that is in: 
`${INSTALL_DIR}/${APP_NAME}/resources/script`
I guess I don't really get how the 'scripts' work in PackageMaker and Apple's documentation doesn't help much there either.

Can someone please help?

Oren

Answer (score 2):

problem with my script was that it didn't have  `!#/bin/sh`at the beginning